# Excel Add In: Clicking a link to a different domain works, but changing the location with JS doesn't

Tags: excel, office-js, webview2

I want to redirect my add in to a URL in a different domain.

I added the domain to the manifest like this:

```
<AppDomains>
   <AppDomain>https://another.domain.com</AppDomain>
</AppDomains>
```

And I can verify that worked because I can add a normal link to my add in like this:

```
<a href="https://another.domain.com/something">Click me</a>
```

Then I click that link and everything is fine.

But if I try to change the location programmatically like this:

```
window.location.href = "https://another.domain.com/something";
```

then the add in stops working, showing only the error screen saying "ADD-IN ERROR Sorry, we can't load the add-in. Please make sure you have network and/or internet connectivity.  Click "Retry" once you're back online."

Is that the expected behaviour? How can I redirect my add in to a different domain?  This used to work fine with the IE11 webview, but it doesn't work with the Chromium webview.

Comment: See [Office Add-in can't find network](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/169288/office-add-in-cant-find-network)

Answer (score 2):

I'm not an expert in Office add-ins, but as far as I understand, when you use `WebView2` in an Office add-in the `WebView2` window runs in an **IFRAME**, while the main document is an internal Office window.

Now when you inject scripts via `CoreWebView2.ExecuteScriptAsync(String)`method, these scripts are injected to the main document according to the docs: [CoreWebView2.ExecuteScriptAsync(String)](https://learn.microsoft.com/da-dk/dotnet/api/microsoft.web.webview2.core.corewebview2.executescriptasync?view=webview2-dotnet-1.0.774.44#Microsoft_Web_WebView2_Core_CoreWebView2_ExecuteScriptAsync_System_String_):

> Runs JavaScript code from the javaScript parameter in the current
> top-level document rendered in the WebView.

This means that `window` will point to the internal Office main window, not your `WebView2`. When you try to navigate this internal window, it crashes. When you instead have a link in your `WebView2` it navigates the `WebView2` iframe.

I see 2 solutions:

**1. Get access to the `Iframe` window object:**

`window.frames[0].location.href = "https://another.domain.com/something";`

Here I assume that there's only one iframe. Otherwise iterate through `window.frames`.

**2. Load your javascript directly into your document:**

Add a script tag to your `<head>` element  with:

`<script src="https://example.com/script.js"><script>`.

Now `window` will be the `WebView2`window. This requires that you control the html. If you do, I recommend this method.

Comment: I control the html, and the javascript I run is running from inside the webiew document, so window should be the right one.  I'll have a look though, we'll see